# Shows dark shade on NavigationBar on adding background image

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uinavigationbar

It shows dark shade on the right side of navigation bar on adding background image.[*only in iPhone 7 and later*]

//code for setting background image

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "top-bg"), forBarMetrics: .Default)
```

[image: Navigation bar image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMO, the image in the background is small and it is repeating itself.

As you can see the left side of the image is dark and when images finishes, it begins with dark shade.

Try this code:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "image")!.resizableImageWithCapInsets(UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0), resizingMode: .Stretch), forBarMetrics: .Default)
```